# CSS/JQ image cropping, something like <div> overflow:hidden with fixed width/height without using div?

Tags: css, image

Just like using overflow:hidden with any fixed width wrapper we can crop images, like for WordPress headers and stuff. I need to get this done without using a wrapper, or somehow forcing a wrapper on the  tags, because what I'm trying to do won't allow me to wrap the img tags with anything, they're on their own.

Can this be done? I was thinking jq but then there would be no fall back if the user didn't have js and the layout would die.

Or using a .png 'frame' with a max width/height on the image with a higher z-index, but that would get complicated.

Just hoping theres a trick I have missed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_clip - that's using clip.